# What is the format of the "apt search" output on debian / ubuntu?

Tags: debian, apt

On Debian / Ubuntu, if I do `apt search`, I get a useful output of packages that match my search with results that look like this:

```
yubikey-val/stable,unstable 2.38-2 all
  One-Time Password (OTP) validation server for YubiKey tokens
```

I understand how most of these fields are populated. However, what does `stable,unstable` mean and how does it get populated?

I have some custom packages that I publish to my own debian repository on S3, and these all say `unknown,unknown` (occasionally `unknown,unknown,now`).

Comment: Is this helpful [Debian Handbook - Creating a Package Repository for APT](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.setup-apt-package-repository.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `stable,unstable` part is built by considering all matching versions of a package in the accessible repositories (as displayed by `apt-cache policy yubikey-val`), and listing the “Suite” entry of the repositories in which a given version is available. `now` is used to indicate the currently-installed version (this corresponds to the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` entry in `apt-cache policy`’s output).

Thus

```
yubikey-val/stable,unstable 2.38-2 all
```

means that the `yubikey-val` package, version 2.38-2, is available for the `all` architecture from the repositories containing the `stable` and `unstable` suites.

When you see `unknown`, that means the repository doesn’t have a “Suite” entry in its `Release` file.