# Installing the latest version of libpcap & libpcap-dev

Tags: debian, libraries, shared-library, pcap

In my docker container I run the following command to install the pcap lib: apt-get install -y libpcap-dev

When I run apt list --installed I see this weird output:

```
libpcap-dev/oldstable,now 1.8.1-6 amd64 [installed]
libpcap0.8-dev/oldstable,now 1.8.1-6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpcap0.8/oldstable,now 1.8.1-6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Does anyone know why it shows "oldstable" and then "now"? Also, how do I force the installation of the latest version of pcap and pcap-dev? I've been searching all over but can't figure it out.

Thanks!

P.S. I'm doing the installation inside a Docker container

Comment: Is your Docker container running Debian Buster ("oldstable") maybe?  As far as as can see, 1.8.1 is the latest _packaged_ version of that library, on Buster (Bullseye ("stable") has 1.10.0). Would you want a later version, then maybe download and compile it yourself from https://www.tcpdump.org/ Or use a more up-to-date Docker image?

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408950/86440) explains “now”. “oldstable” is Debian 10 (“stable” is Debian 11, since mid-August).